# What type of spring is used in this antique receipt holder?

Tags: springs

Pictured is an antique McCaskey Register Co Receipt Holder. I have tried to find a modern equivalent, but I have not had much luck. I am considering building my own, is the spring used a readily available component? What should I be looking for?

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Comment: As a category, this would be called a torsion spring, but I don't know a name for one with that particular shape in the middle.

Comment: You might find something here: http://www.automotioncomponents.co.uk/en/catalog/mechanical/springs/torsion-springs/p1312 (or google for torsion spring images for more suppliers).